# iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to

Tags: airflow, google-authentication

I am trying to store a file into GCS using airflow DAG task.
I have specified my service account info in the "keyfile json" field of the airflow connections page. However, when the dag is run, even though the GCP service account has the "Storage Object Admin" role, I am receiving a permission error:

> ERROR - 403 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/weather_api?projection=noAcl: airflow@xstack-developers-237307.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to weather_api.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/bilguun/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 922, in _run_raw_task
>       result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
>     File "/Users/bilguun/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
>       return_value = self.execute_callable()
>     File "/Users/bilguun/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
>       return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
>     File "/Users/bilguun/airflow/dags/dag_1.py", line 44, in forecast_to_gcs
>       schemas = json.loads(gcs_hook.download(gcs_bucket, 'config/schema.json'))
>     File "/Users/bilguun/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcs_hook.py", line 165, in download
>       bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket)
>     File "/Users/bilguun/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 278, in get_bucket
>       bucket.reload(client=self)
>     File "/Users/bilguun/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_helpers.py", line 130, in reload
>       _target_object=self,
>     File "/Users/bilguun/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 393, in api_request
>       raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)

I have checked the role of my service account multiple times and it says: "Storage Object Admin"

Is there someone who has faced this issue before?

Comment: It seems you are using python_operator. Are you sure that you are using the correct connection?

Comment: @RyanTheCoder I think the above issue is simply due to my account not having the appropriate rights to access the buckets (as it clearly mentioned in the error message).

Comment: Are you able to use that service account to access your GCS object using gsutil?

Comment: @RyanTheCoder yes, without problem.

Comment: Try giving this "roles/storage.legacyBucketReader" to your service account.